# Sorting an arraylist according to number of occurences of similar elements

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have an ArrayList containing `{2,2,1,1,1,5,4,4,4,4,4}` and I want to sort it according to number of occurrences of each element. So it will give `{4,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,5}`. Where do I start?

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortingL{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Integer[] al = new Integer[] {2,2,1,1,1,5,4,4,4,4,4};
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(al));

    sortL(list);

  }

  public static ArrayList<Integer> sortL(ArrayList<Integer> list){


    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are third-party libraries fair game?

Comment: @LouisWasserman no, I want to do it as simple as possible

Comment: If input is `1,2,1,2`, both values occur the same number of time, so all 4 values have the same "weight", so a stable sort (which is what Java sorts are) will leave the 4 values unchanged. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Andreas you mean the output would be `2, 2, 1, 1` or `1, 1, 2, 2`? If so, yes, that's what I want

Comment: No, I meant that both values `1` and `2` occurs twice, so if you *only* sort the values by number of occurrences, they will be left as-is, unless you add secondary sort by value, in which case you need to **define** whether values of same occurrence should sort ascending or descending.

Answer (score 6):

One solution would be to use `Collections#frequency`:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4);

list.sort(Comparator.comparing(i -> Collections.frequency(list, i)).reversed());

System.out.println(list);
```

This will output the expected result:

> [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5]

Comment: If your solution needs to be fast, use Jigar Joshi's answer, as mine seems to complete in `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 3):

For best performance, first build a `Map` of value to count of values. Then sort that by count, and re-build the array.

The effect will be that different values which occur the same number of times will be consolidated. You'd probably want to specify secondary order, then they are consistently sorted.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2,2,1,1,1,5,4,4,4,4,4));
    ArrayList<Integer> sorted = sortL(input);
    System.out.println(sorted); // prints: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5]
}
public static <V extends Comparable<V>> ArrayList<V> sortL(List<V> input) {
    Map<V, ValueCount<V>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (V value : input)
        map.computeIfAbsent(value, ValueCount<V>::new).count++;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ValueCount<V>[] arr = map.values().toArray(new ValueCount[map.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    ArrayList<V> sorted = new ArrayList<>(input.size());
    for (ValueCount<V> vc : arr)
        for (int i = 0; i < vc.count; i++)
            sorted.add(vc.value);
    return sorted;
}
private static final class ValueCount<V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparable<ValueCount<V>> {
    final V value;
    int count;
    ValueCount(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ValueCount<V> that) {
        int cmp = Integer.compare(that.count, this.count); // descending
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = that.value.compareTo(this.value); // descending
        return cmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with O(N) (with little tradeoff of memory space.
)

1. List item
2. Create a hashmap
3. Iterate through your input elements and maintain count of each
   element in hashmap
4. Now iterate through Map's keys and bucket numbers by frequencies
5. Now iterate bucket in reverse order

Code:

```
public List<Integer> frequencyBasedSort(int[] nums, int k) {
    List<Integer>[] bucket = new List[nums.length + 1];
    Map<Integer, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int n : nums) {
        freqMap.put(n, freqMap.getOrDefault(n, 0) + 1);
    }
    for (int key : freqMap.keySet()) {
        int frequency = freqMap.get(key);
        if (bucket[frequency] == null) {
            bucket[frequency] = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        bucket[frequency].add(key);
    }
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = bucket.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (bucket[i] != null) {
            res.addAll(bucket[i]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I already got to point 4. I now have the max number of occurrences. Can you explain more on point 5?

Comment: @JohnP. for example your max comes to `6` (in given example). now loop from 6 to 0 and lookup element in hashmap. if value retrieved from hashmap is non zero print it.

Comment: correction: if retrieved value from hashmap is not `null` print it

Comment: to short circuit the last iteration you can also keep track of number of unique elements

Comment: Your algorithm is not O(N). For example how many iteration will be executed for `{100, 1}` input? Answer is `101`.

Comment: @talex in case of {100, 1} , maxFreq will be 1. so it will loop from 1 to 0. that is O(n). it will go away from O(n) when the frequency distribution is unfair. for example {1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2) if 2 is present 100 times it will iterate 100 times. that is what I have pointed it out in my last point